# iTunes song queue

Tags: cocoa, queue, itunes, scripting-bridge

My app is controlling iTunes via scripting bridge.
Other apps are able to choose a range of songs, and play them in order without having to create a playlist. I have searched the web for examples and red the iTunes.h file a dozen times, but I didn't find a solution.
Can maybe someone of you help me?

Look at the iTunes header file here:
[iTunes.h](http://svn.mehtasw.com/sharedsvn/LyricsHistogram/iTunes.h)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With iTunes 10 it's simply not possible without creating a playlist. The function(which is a known from great other music players) you are talking about is coming in [iTunes 11](http://www.apple.com/itunes/new-itunes/), which will be out in October.
It's called next.
I think just wait a few weeks and then the details will be out how to do it programmatically

Comment: I have really seen this in other applications, like Barquee does. I think this app doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: But I guess thats OK, I'm going to wait for iTunes 11. Would be smart to make big changes when an update is coming anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the songs in your own app and the when you start playing the first song, set a timer to fire at the finishTime of the track you started playing. When the timer fires start playing the next song and repeat the timer. If there are no songs to play end with a stop command to iTunes.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *songsToPlay;

- (void)playNext:(NSTimer *)aTimer {

    if (songsToPlay.count) {
        iTunesTrack *track = songsToPlay.firstObject;
        [track playOnce:YES];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:track.finish - 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(playNext:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        [songsToPlay removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else {
        [iTunes stop];
    }
}
```

Somewhere you prime `songToPlay` with iTunesTrack songs and then call `[self playNext:nil]`.