# Play songs by album/artist on iTunes with Scripting Bridge/Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, itunes, scripting-bridge

Given a name of an album or artist I would like to tell iTunes to play all songs by that artist or on that album. How can I do this? I know how to get all the songs to play by filtering an array with all the tracks, but how do I tell iTunes to play only those I want?

### EDIT

I know I can use this code to get all the tracks I want to play, but I have no idea how to tell iTunes to play them in sucession. Any ideas?

```
// Get the app
iTunesApplication* iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier: @"com.apple.iTunes"];

// Get the library
iTunesSource* library;
for (iTunesSource* thisSource in [iTunes sources]) {
    if ([thisSource kind] == iTunesESrcLibrary) {
        library = thisSource;
        break;
    }
}

SBElementArray* tracks;
for (iTunesPlaylist* playlist in [library playlists]) {
    if ([playlist specialKind] == iTunesESpKMusic) {
        tracks = [playlist searchFor: name only: type == 0 ? iTunesESrAAlbums : iTunesESrAArtists];
     }
 }

 // There. Now what? how do I play all the tracks in 'tracks'?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems iTunes does not have an AppleScript/Scripting Bridge command to play songs by a certain artist/on a certain album. And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538855/itunes-song-queue?rq=1) question, it's not possible to tell iTunes to play a custom list of tracks without creating a new playlist (which I don't want to do). In short, there's really no way to solve this problem...

Answer (score 1):

You can play one songs.

```
iTunesTrack *track = [tracks objectAtIndex:0];
[track playOnce:YES];
```

If you want play several songs, you should create or use a playlist:

```
    for (iTunesUserPlaylist *thisList in playlists) {
        if ([[thisList name] isEqualToString:playlistName]) {
            playlist = thisList;
            break;
        }
    }        

[track duplicateTo:playlist];
[playlist playOnce:YES];
```